# Is there a better way to construct this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design, tree

I have a table like

```
      CommentPaths
============================
ancestor_id | descendant_id
============================
     1            1
     1            2
     1            3
     1            4
     1            5
     1            6
     1            7
     2            2 
     2            4 
     2            5
     4            4
     5            5
     3            3
     3            6
     3            7 
     6            6
     7            7
```

intended to represent a tree structure like

```
        1
      /   \
     2     3
    / \     \
   4   5     6
            /
           7
```

Suppose I delete `2`. Then I need to delete the records pointed to below.

```
      CommentPaths
============================
ancestor_id | descendant_id
============================
     1            1   
     1            2   <-------------
     1            3
     1            4
     1            5
     1            6
     1            7
     2            2   <-------------
     2            4   <-------------
     2            5   <-------------
     4            4   <-------------
     5            5   <-------------
     3            3
     3            6
     3            7 
     6            6
     7            7
```

In other words, when deleting `k` from the tree I need to

1. Delete all rows where `ancestor_id` equals `k`
2. Delete all rows where the `descendant_id` equals there `ancestor_id` is one of the ones from 1.

So my query would look something like

```
SELECT descendant_id FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id=2 AS descs
DELETE FROM CommentPaths WHERE ancestor_id IN descs
DELETE FROM CommentPaths WHERE descendant_id IN descs
```

or is there a fancier, more compact way of doing it????

Comment: Why is everything its own descendant?

Comment: Does ancestor_id = descendant_id?

Comment: @KoebmandSTO That's the way it's presented on pg 36 of this book I'm reading https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns. I never understood why either.

Comment: Trashing the book and making a structure where each entry only appears once will be more compact. Does your code even delete the lines 4 4 and 5 5?

Comment: You need a recursive query. Other wise if you delete 3, only 6 will be delete but not 7, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106947/cte-recursion-to-get-tree-hierarchy

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, it won't. My table is not a parent-child relationship, but an ancestor-descendant relationship.

Comment: IMO, you should also delete `(1, 4), (1, 5)` ;).

Comment: I think are exact the same. And you should take a look

Answer (score 1):

```
-- delete relation from tree
with tree (commentTreeID, ancestor, descendant , path,  src) as 
(
select id,  ancestor_id,  descendant_id , cast ( '-'+ cast(id as varchar(2000)) +'-' as varchar(2000))   , 0from 
CommentPath ct
where ct.ancestor_id = 2
union all
select CT.Id, CT.ancestor_id,  CT.descendant_id ,cast( t.path + '-' + cast(id as varchar(2000)) +'-' as varchar(2000)), 1
from tree t
join CommentPath CT 
 on CT.ancestor_id = t.descendant and
  CHARINDEX (cast( '-' + cast(id as varchar(2000)) +'-' as varchar(2000)), t.path) = 0 and
  t.src != 2
union all
 select CT.Id, CT.descendant_id,  CT.ancestor_id ,cast( t.path + '-' + cast(id as varchar(2000)) +'-' as varchar(2000)), 2
from tree t
join CommentPath CT 
 on CT.descendant_id = t.descendant and
 CHARINDEX(cast( '-' + cast(id as varchar(2000)) +'-' as varchar(2000)), t.path) =0  and
   t.src != 2
 ) 
 delete CT 
  from CommentPath CT 
  join tree t 
  on t.commentTreeID = CT.ID;
```

- The first join is used to go down on tree (src = 1) .
- The second join is used to go up on tree (src = 2 ).

When we go up we don't want to go down or up again = > t.src != 2 makes it happen.

- CHARINDEX (... ) protects us from loops.

Please refer to [**my solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778281/how-do-i-make-a-comment-system-that-deletes-all-descendants-of-a-comment-when-th/34783666#34783666) that I have posted already there. It shows also how to handle `Comment` table.

And here [link in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7058d/1/0) to show some sample that shows what it deletes.